# python: dictionary getting overwritten

Tags: python, dictionary

The value of the dictionary data in the below code is getting overwritten, what might be the cause of overwritting although keys are different.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
data={}
marks = {}
subjects = ["Tamil","English","Maths","Science","Social"]

for i in range(1,3):
  print 'Enter marks for student%d'%i
  for subject in subjects:
    marks[subject] = input("Enter the " + subject + " marks: ")

  data[i]={'marks':marks}
  print data
```

Output of the code:

```
Enter marks for student1
Enter the Tamil marks:  10
Enter the English marks:  20
Enter the Maths marks:  30
Enter the Science marks:  40
Enter the Social marks:  50
{1: {'marks': {'Maths': 30, 'Science': 40, 'Social': 50, 'Tamil': 10, 'English': 20}}}
Enter marks for student2
Enter the Tamil marks:  11
Enter the English marks:  12
Enter the Maths marks:  13
Enter the Science marks:  14
Enter the Social marks:  15
{1: {'marks': {'Maths': 13, 'Science': 14, 'Social': 15, 'Tamil': 11, 'English': 12}}, 2: {'marks': {'Maths': 13, 'Science': 14, 'Social': 15, 'Tamil': 11, 'English': 12}}}
{1: {'marks': {'Maths': 13, 'Science': 14, 'Social': 15, 'Tamil': 11, 'English': 12}}, 2: {'marks': {'Maths': 13, 'Science': 14, 'Social': 15, 'Tamil': 11, 'English': 12}}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are re-using the same dictionary, just use a new one in each iteration:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7
data={}
subjects = ["Tamil","English","Maths","Science","Social"]

for i in range(1,3):
  print 'Enter marks for student%d'%i
  marks = {}
  for subject in subjects:
    marks[subject] = input("Enter the " + subject + " marks: ")

  data[i]={'marks':marks}
  print data
```